# Open pdf file in iBooks from my site

Tags: ipad, pdf, download, ibooks

I need put link to pdf files in my site with conditions..:)

If is a iPad , i want save this pdf in iBooks library and open iBooks showing this file.

Is this possible?

Tks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. When the user views the PDF in Safari and has iBooks installed, there will be a button to open it in iBooks (or other apps that can read PDFs). You cannot automate this though.

Comment: +1 You can't automate this. But you can mimic that behavior in your own iOS app. I know that's not what he's asking, but just in case, here's a good [tutorial](http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/738375724/ios4-sdk-opening-pdfs-in-ibooks)