# How to handle PDF file from Web API in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've this `Web API` post method to generate a PDF:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/pdf")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(CustomType type)
{
    StreamContent pdfContent = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf();

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = pdfContent;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "PDFName.pdf"

    return response;
}
```

In AngularJS I would like to get this PDF-file like this:

```
$http.post("api/pdf", object).then(function (results) {
    var data = results.data;

    //TODO: got PDF, how to handle?

}, function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

But how should I handle the PDF-data in AngularJS? On iPad I would like the PDF to gets opened, but if the file is downloaded or just opened on desktop doesn't matter.

**EDIT1:**

Using [SaveAS JS library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) I'm able to make a working solution on desktop:

```
$http.post("api/pdf", object).then(function (results) {
    var data = results.data;

    var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    saveAs(file, "test.pdf");

}, function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

The file is being downloaded to my desktop directly, but this solution does, for some reason, not work in iOS. Nothing happens. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/zye0e5cg/3/).

Is there another way to display the PDF on my iPad without having to embed the file on my website?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app

Comment: Dennis, you should check the post suggested above by @DavidTansey, it tells you how to use arraybuffer, $sce and embed to fetch and display pdf files in your angularjs apps

Comment: This question has a few methods you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069378/angularjs-dynamic-download-from-response

Comment: I was doing a GET and had to pass in `{ responseType: 'blob' }` to get AngularJS to stop corrupting my PDF. [Gleaned from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585353/how-can-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-pdf-blob-with-forge-and-store-in-localstorage)   `$http.get("api/pdf", { responseType: 'blob' })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are most probably aware, ios devices will not let you download and store a file to memory/disk, as you would do on a desktop/laptop.

**Downloaded items must be opened by an app**

As you are already working on an website, the browser seems a natural candidate.

---

As I surmise *you do not wish to embed the pdf file inside your website*, an alternative would be to **open the pdf in a new browser tab**.

If such a solution is acceptable for you, please check this SO post:

[window.open() in an iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872609/window-open-in-an-ipad-on-load-of-a-frame-does-not-work)

The provided solution does work, but only when Safari is configured so as not to block popups.

---

I am afraid this may well be the **only** viable option for you. [Having the iPad store the pdf into apps like iBooks will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433327/open-pdf-file-in-ibooks-from-my-site), according to this post. It cannot be automated with javaScript.

---

To my knowledge, there is no perfect solution in this case, just a most acceptable solution: open the pdf in a new tab in the browser, if ios has been detected.

If you are interested in this compromise, and run into issues implementing it with `window.open()`, I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

PDFs can be large and when dealing with such large chunk of bytes you should rather `stream` these bytes than gather somewhere into some variable.

Your server side code is already doing that job. But the content-type could be missing.

On the client side I recommend you to open in a separate window/tab as follows:-

```
window.open('http://yourapidomain/api/pdf','resizable,scrollbars');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the server is not setting the mime-type of the response to application/pdf. Try adding a "Content-Type" header to the http response and ipad should open the pdf in the associated app.